# x86 Android phone powerful enough to be used for basic desktop tasks?

Tags: desktop, android, smartphones

With things like Maru OS, Complete Linux Installer and non-root Debian out there, I see more and more people plugging their phone into an external monitor, pairing a bluetooth keyboard and mouse, and using it as a desktop computer. I'm thrilled by this idea.

In case anyone is wondering: the Linux kernel can be made to run Android and GNU userlands at the same time, so that you have both a phone and desktop computer in a single device.

It occurs to me that you would get a better experience on an x86 phone, since the ecosystem of desktop apps is much better for x86 than for ARM. Although they are a tiny minority, I know that there are several nice x86 Android phones out there at the moment. The way Dalvik works means that [they still run the normal Android apps.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/132609/are-apks-architecture-independent)

I know that the Asus Zenphone 2 is quite powerful, but is it powerful enough?

So, I'm looking for a powerful x86 Android phone. It needs to allow "loop devices" (or whatever it's called) This is because that is required for Complete Linux Installer). It also needs to be easy to root and install Xposed Framework on. It should also have hardware allowing me to run desktop apps like Google Chrome with a some basic extensions and several tabs open. I would use apps like Transmission, Skype, Banshee, VLC, Libre Office, OpenShot (no HD), Audacity, GIMP, Photoshop (Wine), Lightroom (Wine), etc. I would probably occasionally run three or four applications at the same time. Is this possible? I mean, my very modest laptop does all this, and it's pretty similar to, for example, the Asus Zenphone 2 in terms of specs.

Keep in mind that this would *not* be a dual boot. Stuff like Maru OS (only ARM currently) actually lets you run GNU and Android at the very same time, so that if you're in desktop mode you can still receive calls, notifications, etc, from Android.

Is there a powerful enough x86 Android phone in the market today to give me a good experience here? My budget is around USD 500, but it can be stretched a bit if there's a perfect phone out there.