# Are there other x86 Android phones than the Asus Zenfone?

Tags: android, smartphones

I've been looking for an Android phone with an x86 processor. I've googled a lot,  searched online and physical retailers, etc,  but so far I've only been able to find the Asus Zenfone.

I'm looking for a phone with a quad or dual core x86 processor. I want at least 2 GHz of processing power and at least 2 GB of RAM. Any candidates must have a micro SD card slot.

Are there any other options than the Asus Zenfone?

Comment: Using a German price comparison site I can only find Asus devices with Atom processors from 2015 onward, which doesn't surprise me after Intel's announcement to cancel the 2016 SoC products and focus on higher margin products like premium tablets (running Windows I guess).

Comment: Intel has discontinued its smartphone/Atom lines a few weeks ago. No more x86 phones will be made. That also means that no development should be expected for the existing x86 phones.

Comment: That' sucks. Can you provide a source? And what do you mean by "no more development"?  Because android apps are independent of architecture.

Comment: Atom series being discontinued does not necessarily spell the end, as the core m series is more powerful and as energy efficient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found one additional phone which meets almost all your requirements (and is not Asus Zenfone 2 or Asus Zenfone Zoom or other Asus).

### [Lenovo K80](http://www.gsmarena.com/lenovo_k80-7216.php)

- CPU: [Intel Atom Z3560](http://ark.intel.com/products/81194/Intel-Atom-Processor-Z3560-2M-Cache-up-to-1_83-GHz) (x64 quad core processor, but only 1.83 GHz frequency. It's the same processor like in Asus ZenFone 2 ZE550ML.)
- GPU: [PowerVR G6430](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Imagination-PowerVR-G6430.110717.0.html)
- 2 GB or 4 GB RAM (it depends which version)
- 5.5" LCD IPS 1920 x 1080
- Antutu score: 41380
- Storage: 32 GB or 64 GB (no SD cards support which can disqualify this phone for you)

It can be bought:

- [2GB RAM - 32GB ROM version - $230](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B015HAIHCK) - on Amazon.com
- [4GB RAM - 64 GB ROM version - $180 + tax](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Original-Lenovo-K80-K80M-4G-LTE-Mobile-Phone-Dual-SIM-Intel-64Bit-Quad-Core-5-5/32334874089.html?spm=2114.40010408.3.1.X9SX2p) - I only found it on AliExpress.com (Goldway) I actually bought there my Xiaomi Redmi Note 2 and I was really happy with this transaction

Comment: Thanks for the effort. This phone looks very nice, but the lack of SD card support is indeed a drawback.

Comment: @Fiksdal It's only one which I found with "good" Atom other than Asus. There are rumors about [Microsoft Surface Phone](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/microsoft-surface-mobile-phone-news/) but when it will be avaliable we don't know... What do you need this phone (processor) for ? Do you want to put normal OS on it ?

Comment: Yeah, I know, it's possible that there are in fact no other such phones at all. Oh, Microsoft? Well, I would never run Windows Phone, though. I want Android. As for why I want x86, read this: http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2643/x86-android-phone-powerful-enough-to-be-used-for-basic-desktop-tasks

Comment: @Fiksdal Yes, you are right. They are not the same but finally answer for other question will be the same because you are asking about powerful x86 Android phone (not Asus because you are listing it there) so there is only Lenovo left.

Comment: Yes, kind of. And in the other question, I also specify that the phone needs to support "loop devices".

Comment: @Fiksdal You are right. But I really don't know where to find this information about Lenovo K80 and really don't know if any of this devices supports it (Asus ZenFone or Lenovo K80).

Comment: Yes. I think the only way to find out is to try. I will probably buy the top range Zenfone. It has 2.2 GHz or something and 4GB RAM.

Comment: @Fiksdal I've just read article about [incomming release of ASUS Zenfone 3](https://www.androidpit.com/asus-zenfone-3-price-release-date-specs-features) May/June. Maybe it's good idea to wait for it. There is possibility that it will use x64 CPU (like Zenfone 2) maybe with better specs fitting your requirements even more.

Comment: Update: The ASUS Zenfone 3 will have an ARM processor.

Answer (score -1):

Old topic, however no complete answer.

Everybody knows GSM Arena web site with thousands of device specs? Then it's as easy as searching using their dedicated form. Even though the search feature doesn't list intel CPUs in chipset selection, one can find those using free text.

Following search returns (at the time of writing) 34 devices (among 3789+ Android-based devices), some being just variants of one another:

https://www.gsmarena.com/results.php3?sFreeText=INTEL&sOSes=2

Here is the search URL and list extracted based on OP's requirements:

https://www.gsmarena.com/results.php3?nCpuMHzMin=2000&nRamMin=2000&sFreeText=INTEL&sOSes=2&idCardslot=1

```
Asus Zenfone 2 ZE551ML Android smartphone. Announced Jan 2015. Features 5.5″ IPS LCD display, Intel Atom Z3580 chipset, 13 MP primary camera, 5 MP front camera, 3000 mAh battery, 64 GB storage, 4 GB RAM, Corning Gorilla Glass 3

Asus Zenfone 5 A500CG (2014) Android smartphone. Announced Jan 2014. Features 5.0″ IPS LCD display, Intel Atom Z2580 chipset, 8 MP primary camera, 2 MP front camera, 2110 mAh battery, 32 GB storage, 2 GB RAM, Corning Gorilla Glass 3.

Asus Zenfone 6 A600CG Android smartphone. Announced Jan 2014. Features 6.0″ IPS LCD display, Intel Atom Z2580 chipset, 13 MP primary camera, 2 MP front camera, 3300 mAh battery, 32 GB storage, 2 GB RAM, Corning Gorilla Glass 3.

Asus Zenfone 2 Deluxe ZE551ML Android smartphone. Announced Aug 2015. Features 5.5″ IPS LCD display, Intel Atom Z3580 chipset, 13 MP primary camera, 5 MP front camera, 3000 mAh battery, 256 GB storage, 4 GB RAM, Corning Gorilla Glass 3.

Asus Zenfone Zoom ZX551ML Android smartphone. Announced Sep 2015. Features 5.5″ IPS LCD display, Intel Atom Z3590 chipset, 13 MP primary camera, 5 MP front camera, 3000 mAh battery, 128 GB storage, 4 GB RAM, Corning Gorilla Glass 4.

Asus Zenfone Zoom ZX550 Android smartphone. Announced Jan 2015. Features 5.5″ IPS LCD display, Intel Atom Z3580 chipset, 13 MP primary camera, 5 MP front camera, 3000 mAh battery, 128 GB storage, 4 GB RAM, Corning Gorilla Glass 3.

Asus Fonepad Note FHD6 Android smartphone. Announced Jun 2013. Features 6.0″ Super IPS+ LCD display, Intel Atom Z2580 chipset, 8 MP primary camera, 1.2 MP front camera, 3200 mAh battery, 32 GB storage, 2 GB RAM.

ZTE Geek V975 Android smartphone. Announced Apr 2013. Features 5.0″ IPS LCD display, Intel Atom Z2580 chipset, 8 MP primary camera, 1 MP front camera, 2300 mAh battery, 16 GB storage, 2 GB RAM, Corning Gorilla Glass.
```

Comment: Welcome to Hardware Recs! We try to refrain from posting link-centric answers, as they decrease legibility and are susceptible to link rot. Could you add a quick summary of the available phones to the body of your answer?